Error running flutter app on emulator after first run
When I ran my flutter app on an android emulator for the first time it ran smoothly. However, after the first launch, it shows an error.
Here is the error:
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
I/ample.food_fete( 6664): Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:41429/ZIJH4M0Maio=/ws
9
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 6664): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183 GL error 0x502
W/Parcel  ( 6664): Expecting binder but got null!


I have tried to uninstall android studio updating things to the latest but this problem persists. Is there anyone who can help me?

did you check your setup status with flutter doctor -v? link. Please, include the result of the command run in the question.

Yes Flutter doctor report is fine.
Another thing I found after it shows error from second time. I opened the app info from emulator and deleted the cache and then rerun it and it ran that time.
Actually I am not able to understand what is going wrong!
Another information might be crucial whenever I run a flutter app this warning shows at first :
" Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered."

check if you have a proper setup of all gradle files. create a new project and verify line-by-line. If your codebase has something a new project doesn't, try to remove it or change it accordinly.

consult some GitHub issues like this one. Might be a problem with your async code.

@ardiien -- sorry, that's completely off the track. There's absolutely nothing wrong with our apps. The problem is with the emulator. No Gradle, no async, nothing else. The very same app that runs when installed from fresh on the emulator will not run the second time (the app bar might appear but the actual app content not). If you remove it, reinstall it, wipe the emulator or cold boot it, it will run again for a single time.

It's a well-known problem, discussed in many places, eg. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/146890

The current consensus in the relevant Flutter issue (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/146890) seems to be that this is a regression error present in the current emulator versions, not fixed yet. Many report that the only practical workaround is to downgrade to an earlier version like 34.1.20. There are other attempts among the replies there as well, if you feel like experimenting.
I can confirm that this rollback works. Go directly to https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive and follow the instructions there. Be sure to download version 34.1.20. You have to look for it because the versions are sorted by date and not version, the actual date to look for is April 1, 2024; apparently not a joke. :-)

Steps to reproduce

flutter create test_drive
cd test_drive
Start Android emulator
flutter run
Press the back button/close the app
Reopen the app from the launcher
Expected results: The app runs normally and shows correctly.
Actual results: The app does not render correctly and GL/GLESv2 errors are thrown. It is fixed when clearing the data of the app, but it happens again after it is re-opened.

error:
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 5842): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502

image with error
flutter doctor
sdk tools
avd settings

I think the error may be related to acceleration for the Android Emulator: Configure hardware acceleration for the Android Emulator

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Run emulator like this: emulator -avd Pixel_8_Pro -gpu host. Its helped me

For now, I have found a way. After first run everytime it shows this error. Now before starting the app I go into that app info and delete the cache then it runs fine without any oepengl error. And with running on hardware mode my emulator runs good. But still sometimes emulator does not open correctly then close and open it again works. I do not know what is the main problem that is causing this problm=em. But I think it is also related to that error which shows flutter doctor --android-licenses                                                                   ✔  Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times. Warning: Errors during XML parse:                                                Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.              [=======================================] 100% Computing updates...              All SDK package licenses accepted. 
So here as it was not able to comprehend those XML files maybe it also could be because of that opengl is not able to respond well.
